# set the default locale as arabic in android app start

Tags: android, localization

I am new to android application development.I have two languages in my application(English,arabic).I want to start the app with arabic language.But default it starts with english.How can i change it to arabic.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Android system selects which resources to load, based on the device's locale
```

Quoted from [android Localization chapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Go through this to learn more.